# sqs policy attribute error when the prinicpal is a role arn

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, permissions, amazon-sqs, policy

I encountered an error when creating a policy for a sqs queue when specifying the principal as a role arn.

Here is the code I have

```
public void addQueuePermission(String queueName) {
        try {
            String museBackendRoleArn = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxx:role/yyyyyyyy";
            SQSActions[] eventQueueActions = {SQSActions.CreateQueue, SQSActions.ReceiveMessage, SQSActions.SendMessage};

            String queueURL = amazonSQS.getQueueUrl(queueName).getQueueUrl();
            List<String> sqsAttributes = new ArrayList<>();
            sqsAttributes.add("QueueArn");
            Map<String, String> att = amazonSQS.getQueueAttributes(queueURL, sqsAttributes).getAttributes();

            Map<String, String> options = new HashMap<>();
            options.put("Policy", createSQSPolicy(Statement.Effect.Allow, museBackendRoleArn, att.get("QueueArn"),
                    eventQueueActions).toJson());
            amazonSQS.setQueueAttributes(queueURL, options);
        } catch(AmazonServiceException ignore) {
            logger.error(ignore.getMessage());
        }
    }

 public static Policy createSQSPolicy(Statement.Effect effect, String principal, String resourceArn, SQSActions[] sqsActions, String sourceArn) {
        Statement statement = new Statement(effect)
                .withActions(sqsActions)
                .withPrincipals(new Principal(principal))
                .withResources(new Resource(resourceArn));
        return new Policy().withStatements(statement);
    }
```

The code returns a 400 error with the error message "Invalid value for the parameter Policy."

I tried the same policy through aws console and it works fine. I am using aws java sdk version 1.11.59

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.59</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same error and I was stumped until I tried ARNs for roles that actually exist.

It looks like SQS validates that the AWS principals actually exist.

I wanted to create a policy that allows roles that still need to be created later, but now I'll need to first create the roles and then update the policy to allow those roles